# CMYK color space

Tags: cmyk

How find that a color is in CMYK color space or not (other than adobe softwares)?

[image]

Comment: By "color" I guess you mean "RGB color", right? That diagram is heavily simplified and only shows the principle. To check if an RGB color on the screen is possible to print in CMYK on paper, you need to know both the *RGB color profile* and the *CMYK color profile*. You don't have to use Adobe software, but you need some software that supports *color profiles* and can do the conversion for you.

Comment: That diagram is vastly over-simplified. Some RGB colour spaces are larger than the human vision space - see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ProPhoto_RGB_color_space for some background reading.

Comment: In addition to what @Tetsujin said, there also CMYK colours outside of the RGB gamut (yes, you read that right the first time). [This image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndh0e.jpg) is a more accurate representation.

Comment: @Tetsujin its not really suprising that it exceeds human vision it also exceed possible physics of light. Also its worth noting that the actual plot is 3dimensional your just seeing one slice of it. Cmyk has a considerable advantage on the draker slices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other free software such as Krita and GIMP are capable of showing when RGB colours are out of the CMYK gamut for a particular CMYK ICC colour profile. You don't have to use Adobe software for this.

Although GIMP doesn't support CMYK mode itself (but Krita does), you can still enable colour management in the preferences, and download a CMYK ICC colour profile to use from the [International Colour Consortium website](https://color.org/index.xalter).

Then you can go into *Edit > Preferences* and enable colour management, and use the CMYK ICC profile you downloaded for the Soft-Proofing profile. Then you can go into *View > Colour Management*, switch on "Proof Colours", and switch on "Mark out of Gamut Colours".

Here's an example I made.  I have painted some blue lines in GIMP using 00ffff which is an out of gamut colour for CMYK printing (shown on the left), and the view on the right shows colour proofing enabled, with the out of gamut warning enabled. GIMP's default is to display out of gamut areas with a purple overlay.

[image]

Comment: @Angel see this Document properties dialog in Scribus https://i.stack.imgur.com/vkPof.png   That freebie shows unprintable (=out of gamut) colors and also simulates on the screen what CMYK printing would give. For actual printing it can generate the print PDF. This also can be interesting:   https://creativepro.com/out-of-gamut-the-proof-is-on-your-monitor/ At least those concepts are good to know if one uses CMYK although the text refers ancient Photoshop.